# jquery and change html 5 video source on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this has been asked before but for some reason that strategy doesn't seem to be working for me.

this is my code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#foo').click(function() {
        var videoFile = 'video/law_cash.mp4';
        $('#video_container video source').attr('src', videoFile);
        });
    });
```

the click function works and also when I check in firebug the video/law_cash.mp4 shows up in the right area. It just wont load when I click

EDIT: this is what im actually trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var knicks = 'video/knicks_therapist.m4v';
        law = 'video/law_cash.mp4';
        fit = 'video/fit_some.mp4';
        texas = 'video/texas_familia.mp4';
        partner = 'video/drug.m4v';
        keyspan = 'video/keyspan_nrg.mov';

    $('#law').click(function() {
        $('#video_container video source').attr('src', law);
        $('#video_container video source').load();
    });

    $('#knicks').click(function() {
        $('#video_container video source').attr('src', knicks);
        $('#video_container video source').load();
    });

    $('#fit').click(function() {
        $('#video_container video source').attr('src', fit);
        $('#video_container video source').load();
    });

    $('#texas').click(function() {
        $('#video_container video source').attr('src', texas);
        $('#video_container video source').load();
    });

    $('#partner').click(function() {
        $('#video_container video source').attr('src', partner);
        $('#video_container video source').load();
    });

    $('#keyspan').click(function() {
        $('#video_container video source').attr('src', keyspan);
        $('#video_container video source').load();
    });
});
```

html:

```
<a id="law" href="#">BLAH</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't support MPEG audio/video formats... dunno why.

EDIT: If you have an `onerror` event registered then it would fire, and the video element's `error` object will tell you `MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED`

Comment: Im not using firefox as my main test browser though. I only used firefox to see if I would get any errors, just incase web inspector (safari) didnt pick it up.

Comment: Well, you should check the video element's `canPlayType('video/mpeg')` return value - if it's empty or `"no"` then the problem is with the browser, not your code.

Answer (score 2):

In the original example, I believe the code snippet to load the video should be

```
$('#video_container video').load();
```

(without 'source' tag after 'video' tag)

Comment: Thanks, this enables me to load a video, but the flowplayer theme is now broken

Answer (score 0):

Just use javascript

```
video.src = 'new/url/video.ogv';
video.load();  // Load the new video
video.play();  // Play it
```

Comment: Not a good answer for several reasons - one being that AVI is a wrapper format and browsers depend heavily on formats and codecs, another being that it doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Sorry about the format (i have fixed it).  But the example (other than the format error) works perfectly in Firefox and Chromium for me.  It switches the curently playing video to the video at `new/url/video.ogv`.

Comment: Notice, however, that Robert's code contains MP4, which is the actual cause of his problem ;)

Comment: I thought the source of his problem was that he did not call `load()`.  Excuse my mistake.

Comment: I updated the code with what i'm actually trying to achieve. And yes all those different formats work in safari. This is an internal thing so I don't really care if it doesn't work on other browsers.